# Remove files from GitHub

Tags: git, github

I have deleted some files from local computer and pushed the changes to Github. However I want to remove those changes in GitHub also. I tried git rm . Not working. Any idea how to remove those files.[Here is the file I want to remove](https://i.stack.imgur.com/96yL2.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: `git rm` *adds* something. Specifically, it *adds a removal*. You then commit this to commit the added removal. The old files are still there in the old commits. That's how a version control system works. *Every* file exists *forever* in the form in which it's committed. If the files aren't sensitive data, and aren't problematically huge, it's not worth rewriting history to eliminate them.

Comment: If they *are* sensitive data, use StackOverflow's search function to find the many existing answers about removing sensitive data from GitHub.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to remove the file from the Git repository forcefully then use -f :

git rm -f file1.txt
git commit -m "remove file1.txt"

If you want to remove from github only and want in your local
git rm --cached file1.txt
git commit -m "remove file1.txt"

Than push to your relative branch
git push origin <branch_name>

Comment: I have already deleted that file in local PC. but it shows in GitHub. Also if i want to remove that file it shows like fatal: pathspec 'doc/source/_static/images/omar/image2.jpg' did not match any files